# Neo4j embedded online backup using Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, neo4j, backup, database-backups

I am using Neo4j(embedded) Enterprise edition 1.8.3. I tried to do the online backup using the code below

```
  def backup_data()
  {
        val backupPath: File = new File("D:/neo4j/data/backup/")
        val backup = OnlineBackup.from( "127.0.0.1" )
        if(backupPath.list().length > 0)
        {
            backup.incremental( backupPath.getPath(), false )
        }
        else
        {
        backup.full( backupPath.getPath() );
        }
  }
```

The above code is working fine in Windows but I got the error  **Client could not connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:6362** with the same code in Ubuntu. What should I change to make it work in Ubuntu?

Comment: "Could not connect" is a straightforward error message.  Are you running a neo4j service on port 6362 of that Ubuntu machine (localhost)?  I'm guessing no -- if you switched machines, localhost always refers to the machine you're on (ditto 127.0.0.1) and also that's a non-standard port for neo4j.